# High CPU usage from UEventObserver and inputmethod.latin (Nexus S)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-s, performance, troubleshooting

I have kept my Google Nexus S up to date with the latest Android O/S since I've owned it and its always had performance problems to varying degrees. I'm currently running:

```
Android version: 4.1.2
Baseband version: I9023XXKI1
Kernel version: 3.0.31-g5894150
Build number: JZO54K
Uptime: 145:35:00
```

Currently the performance is particularly bad. The UI is generally very sluggish, apps can take a long time to open or switch, occasionally the home screen appears empty after switching away from a "big" app (e.g. Bad Piggies or Chrome) almost as if the shell had crashed and restarted. The performance seems to deteriorate the longer the phone has been without a reboot. There is a bug where the phone think its still charging after being unplugged. I am not sure if this is associated with the performance issue.

I tried various performance monitoring apps but none of them told me anything useful. I finally installed a terminal emulator and ran the trusty top. Here are the results:

[image: top]

These two threads: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin and UEventObserver, appear to consistently be using high CPU. I have seem UEventObserver using as much as 40-50%. Regarding the inputmethod.latin I am assuming this is keyboard related but I am only using the standard Android keyboard so the high CPU usage is inexplicable.

Any theories about what is going on?

How can I fix these two threads that are hogging the CPU?

Comment: Have you checked around on [XDA](http://xda-developers.com)?

Comment: as matter of interest, you're using Android Terminal Emulator right? Possibly that even?

Comment: I've done a fair bit of googling, but nothing seems to come up with the specific searches for the thread names. Yes I think its Android Terminal Emulator

Comment: What is the uptime on that nexus s? Quite possibly you could have stumbled on a kernel glitch? In short, you cannot "*fix these two threads that are hogging the CPU*", the binder_X I see in there, some service must have died and ended up in repeat restart die loop...

Comment: Might help to include a logcat of what's going on... :)

Comment: Uptime added. Researching 'logcat'...

Answer (score 0):

You can check "adb shell getevent" to see which events are coming at the time of this high CPU. That may help.